# Writing farsi in Texstudio with it's Quick start "Wizard"

Tags: texstudio, babel, arabic

Simple configuration for writing Farsi results in:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[farsi]{babel}
\author{S. M. Saadatmand}
\begin{document}
    سلام %I've only added this
\end{document}
```

But it results this error:

```
line 133: Encoding scheme `LAE' unknown. ...ntencoding{LAE}\fi\selectfont\alefhamza}}
line 133: Command \alefhamza unavailable in encoding OT1. ...ntencoding{LAE}\fi\selectfont\alefhamza}}
line 135: Encoding scheme `LAE' unknown. ... \fontencoding{LAE}\fi\selectfont\Haa}}
line 135: Command \Haa unavailable in encoding OT1. ... \fontencoding{LAE}\fi\selectfont\Haa}}
line 137: Encoding scheme `LAE' unknown. ... \fontencoding{LAE}\fi\selectfont\damma}}
line 137: Command \damma unavailable in encoding OT1. ... \fontencoding{LAE}\fi\selectfont\damma}}
line 139: Encoding scheme `LAE' unknown. ... \fontencoding{LAE}\fi\selectfont\kasra}}
line 139: Command \kasra unavailable in encoding OT1. ... \fontencoding{LAE}\fi\selectfont\kasra}}
line 6: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character س (U+0633)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. س
line 6: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ل (U+0644)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. سل
line 6: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ا (U+0627)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. سلا
line 6: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character م (U+0645)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. سلام
```

I think also it is necessary to add English in Babel input argument.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load the requested font encoding:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi]{babel}
\author{S. M. Saadatmand}
\begin{document}
    سلام %I've only added this
\end{document}
```

**EDIT.** If you are using XeTeX or LuaTeX, then you shouldn't load `inputenc` or `fontenc`. With LuaTeX:

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main,import]{persian}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\author{S. M. Saadatmand}
\begin{document}
    سلام %I've only added this
\end{document}
```

With XeTeX, the bidi method is `bidi=bidi-r`. You need a recent version of `babel`. See the manual for further info (it provides some examples with the Arabic script). See also the examples on https://github.com/latex3/babel/tree/master/samples.

Alternatively, you may use polyglossia (afaik, only XeTeX).

Comment: Now there is no error when I click on green play button, but it can't show it in right side of editor, also I have some error: `: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
line 6: Font shape `LAE/lmr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `LAE/cmr/m/n' instead
line 6: Font shape `LFE/lmr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `LFE/cmr/m/n' instead
: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`

Comment: Those error were listed in logs not in messages. Surprisingly, this code is just working well in TeXworks!!

Comment: So, you are using XeTeX or LuaTeX. I've edited my answer.

Comment: You are write I've changed it to pdftex and everything is nicely worked, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! Another Q: How many kind of `fontenc` are vailible and how can I learn them?

Comment: They've told in document basic-r is only in LauTeX, I wonder why `basic` works in PdfLaTeX, albeit it tells a warning but, works. I want to know what are the acceptable kinds for `fontenc` and their uses, but didn't find any document can you tell me where I can find?